# UIViewControllerRepresentable not working correctly when wrapped in AnyView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've created this very simple wrapper with `UIViewControllerRepresentable`:

```swift
struct ViewControllerWrapperView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let controller: UIViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerWrapperView>) -> UIViewController {
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ViewControllerWrapperView>) {}
}
```

Using it to display ViewControllers in a SwiftUI view works fine:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var viewSwitch: Bool = true

    let blueView: ViewControllerWrapperView = {
        let blueViewController = UIViewController()
        blueViewController.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return ViewControllerWrapperView(controller: blueViewController)
    }()

    let redView: ViewControllerWrapperView = {
        let redViewController = UIViewController()
        redViewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
        return ViewControllerWrapperView(controller: redViewController)
    }()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Switch") { viewSwitch.toggle() }

        if viewSwitch {
            blueView
        } else {
            redView
        }
    }
}
```

But as soon as I wrap the `ViewControllerWrapperView`s in `AnyView` they stop working properly:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var viewSwitch: Bool = true

    let blueView: AnyView = {
        let blueViewController = UIViewController()
        blueViewController.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return AnyView(ViewControllerWrapperView(controller: blueViewController))
    }()

    let redView: AnyView = {
        let redViewController = UIViewController()
        redViewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
        return AnyView(ViewControllerWrapperView(controller: redViewController))
    }()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Switch") { viewSwitch.toggle() }

        if viewSwitch {
            blueView
        } else {
            redView
        }
    }
}
```

With `AnyView` the views don't switch when the button is tapped. Looking a bit deeper into it, I discovered the following:

For both scenarios when first displaying the view:

1. `makeUIViewController` is called on the `ViewControllerWrapperView` for the blue view.
2. `updateUIViewController` is called on the `ViewControllerWrapperView` for the blue view and the parameter `uiViewController` is the blue ViewController.

Now without `AnyView` when the switch button is tapped the life cycle of the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` is executed as supposed to:

1. `updateUIViewController` is called on the `ViewControllerWrapperView` for the blue view and the parameter `uiViewController` is the blue ViewController.
2. `makeUIViewController` is called on the `ViewControllerWrapperView` for the red view.
3. `updateUIViewController` is called on the `ViewControllerWrapperView` for the red view and the parameter `uiViewController` is the red ViewController.
4. `dismantleUIViewController` is called and the parameter `uiViewController` is the blue view.

**But** with `AnyView` when tapping the switch button, the only thing that happens is:

1. `updateUIViewController` is called on the `ViewControllerWrapperView` for the **RED** view and the parameter `uiViewController` is the **BLUE** ViewController.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in SwiftUI?

Comment: You [should avoid using AnyView](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/avoiding-anyview-in-swiftui/) when possible.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for the well-intentioned hint, but for my use case I'm pretty sure that I can't avoid `AnyView`.

Comment: look into `@ViewBuilder` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder

Comment: @ag_aok why do you think you need `AnyView`? Did you actually read the article I linked, which explains how to avoid using it?

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter Thanks, I know about `@ViewBuilder`. In this case I really need to know why `AnyView` doesn't work with `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I've read that article in the past and know the suggested techniques. They don't apply in my case.

Comment: @ag_aok maybe if you actually explained your use case people would be able to help. The code in your question does not require the use of `AnyView` at all, so if you think you need `AnyView`, either your code is not a [mcve] or you don't actually need `AnyView`, as several of us are trying to point out to you repeatedly.

Comment: @DávidPásztor It doesn't really have anything to do with the question, but sure. I'm writing a container view that has a segmented control at the top and displays a corresponding view below it. Similar to a TabView but with the selections at the top. The container view is initialized by an array of `Segment` structs that have different properties, one of them being the view that should be displayed. I use a `@ViewBuilder` in the `init` of `Segment` but ultimately when displaying it in the container view I need to wrap it in `AnyView` because the different segments can have different view types

Comment: @DávidPásztor actually in order to have a minimal reproducible example, I chose to leave all the other code out, since it's irrelevant to the question. The question is about why `UIViewControllerRepresentable` doesn't work with `AnyView` and not about how to write a segment container view or how to avoid `AnyView`. Even if I could avoid `AnyView` the question should be addressed, since it could be a bug in SwiftUI and should be reported if that's the case.

Comment: Your makeUIViewController is not making

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something or is this a bug in SwiftUI?

It is not a bug, `AnyView` erases type differences, so rendering `body` SwiftUI engine sees only `AnyView` replaced with `AnyView` which are equal, so engine does not *replace* existed view, but just refreshes it (because state has been changed) that results in `updateUIViewController` call. All is as expected.

And that's why usage of `AnyView` should be very very careful and meaningful   with clear understanding of process and consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what my first thought was as well. I just thought that `AnyView` when updating itself should be able to recognize that the view that is wrapped in it are two different views. It works when the views have different types, but I guess since it notices, that it's the same type it only calls update. Still don't fully understand why.

Comment: unreasonable expectations - it should not.

Comment: Since `AnyView` destroys the view hierarchy and creates a new one when the view type inside of it changes, my thinking was it always does this. But as it seems, if the type stays the same, it only triggers a re-render. Which makes sense and is usually fine, but in combination with `UIViewControllerRepresentable` this results in the problem above. Thanks, I accepted your answer.